# Programmatically creating/deleting tasks for task scheduler

Tags: c++, windows, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to create a task (via C++) that should be executed with highest privileges, although I cannot see in the docs for Task Scheduler how to set that flag (which is available via the Task Scheduler UI).

Ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the [`ITaskDefinition::Principal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381319.aspx) property. Set [`RunLevel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380747.aspx) in [`IPrincipal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380742.aspx) to `TASK_RUNLEVEL_HIGHEST`.

Comment: Thanks! Me thinks that's just what I need :)

Answer (score 2):

[Here is an example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446861%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code snippet how to setup run level.

```
IPrincipal *pPrincipal = NULL;
hr = pTask->get_Principal(&pPrincipal);
if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot get principal pointer: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return false;
    }
//  Set up principal run level to the highest one
hr = pPrincipal->put_RunLevel(TASK_RUNLEVEL_HIGHEST);
pPrincipal->Release();
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("\nCannot put principal info: %x", hr);
    pRootFolder->Release();
    pTask->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: amazing, there is also the default option, `Stop the task if it is running longer than` it is automatically set to 3 days, how do i turn that off ? Thank you

Comment: also there is `Stop if the computer ceases to be idle` i want to get that to `0` as well,  iwant my task to keep running always

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to explore [MSDN Task Scheduler Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Also, check [Schtasks.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).